# How to add optional argument in perl

Tags: perl

I want to do command line argument parsing for a directory path in perl. I want to make this argument as optional. 
so when the user gives path, it showed be assigned to a variable $release_model else it will execute other code I have written for finding directory from main directory. I am new to perl but somehow coded following. Can anybody help?

```
Getopt::Long
my $command_line = $GetOptions(\%Opts, "help|h","email=s@","test","model");
if($command_line==0){
print "$PROGRAM: no arguments are given";
Usage{};
}
else die "No arguments were given"
```

But it doesn't accept model as optional argument and throws error.

I just started working with perl.

Comment: "throws error" is not a helpful diagnostic message. What error? Your `$GetOptions(...)` construction looks like an error. Is that the real code? A bare `Getopt::Long` (no semicolon? not `use Getopt::Long;`?) also looks like an error.

Comment: hi mob, yes it is real code. I am novice to perl. never worked earlier with perl.

Comment: Then why did you substantially deviate from the code in the [documentation](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Getopt::Long)?  Refer to the code in the Synopsis.

Comment: hi. i am novice to perl. i never used perl before. so might be i am wrong everywhere. i thought some perl expert can help me correcting code.

Comment: There's almost 20 errors in there. Either you're asking us to write your code for you (not appropriate), or you're asking us to teach you Perl (not appropriate).

Comment: at least the code seems written by himself.

Answer (score 1):

It is quite hard to guess what exactly you are after as the code provided contains lots of errors and other features not described. But to start learning with something simple, here is something that I hope matches your requirements.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Getopt::Long;

my $release_model = '/path/to/"main directory"'; # default value

GetOptions( 'model=s' => \$release_model )
    or die("Error in command line arguments\n");

print "Release model is: $release_model\n";
```

If you save this to a file (e.g. `my_program.pl`) and make it executable then you can see it provides these features:

1. If you call it without arguments `./my_program.pl`, the default value of `$release_model` will be used.
2. If you call it with argument `model` (e.g. `./my_program.pl --model /another/directory`), the provided value will be assigned to `$release_model`.
3. If you call it with wrong arguments (e.g. `./my_program.pl --mdoel`), it prints reasonable error message and exits.

Try it yourself. And go and read some tutorial on Perl if you want to do some serious work.